# Failed to load plugin "windows" в Qt 5.0.1

Tags: qt

Не запускается проект Qt 5.0.1.

Код нормально компилируется. При запуске через "Сборка->Запустить" программа запускается. При запуске релиз версии из проводника ничего не происходит. При запуске дебаг версии из проводника имею

[image]

Comment: Оу... Это был первый проект на qt 5.0.1. Решил собрать просто шаблонное приложение, то есть просто создал qt приложение, и оно тоже не запустилось. Поэксперементировал, и выходит, что ни один проект не запускается из проводника.

Comment: Может проблема в Windows XP? :)

Comment: Звучит, конечно, очень странно, но так уж и быть, проверил на семерке. Тоже самое.

Comment: Нашел такое решение: http://habrahabr.ru/post/188816/

Answer (score 3):

Вот как пофиксить:

в комплекте с *Qt Creator* идёт специальная консоль. В пуск *Qt* набери, она одна.

Там пишешь:

```
windeployqt "C:\Qt projects\release\прога.exe"
```

После этого в директории с `exe` появятся нужные `dll`, можно будет запустить.